# How to monitor redis keys change?

Tags: debugging, redis

I have an application with redis part which I need to debug. I want to monitor when application get requests and which redis keys has been changed (deleted or created). Does anyone know how to monitor redis keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to look at [monitor](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command. It should only be used for debugging.